# Find the value of $\sum^{n-1}_{m=1}\left(\frac{1}{n-m}+\frac{1}{n+m}\right)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find the value of 
$$\sum^{n-1}_{m=1}\left(\frac{1}{n-m}+\frac{1}{n+m}\right)$$ 
I used WolframAlpha obtaining
$$\psi^{(0)}(2n)-\frac{1}{n}+\gamma$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi^{(k)}(x)$ is the k-th derivative of the digamma function. But I can not prove it. Any suggestions please?

Comment: The $\psi^{(0)}$ formula is a mere rewriting, mainly useless. You might want to use $$\sum^{n-1}_{m=1}\left(\frac{1}{n-m}+\frac{1}{n+m}\right)=\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}+\sum^{2n-1}_{i=n+1}\frac{1}{i}=\sum^{2n-1}_{m=1}\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: please fix you $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum is just $H_{2n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$, where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number, defined as:
$$ H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}.$$
$H_n$ can be defined also for non-integer $n$s, since $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x+1)=\psi(x+1)$ satisfies the recursive relation $f(x+1)=f(x)+\frac{1}{x}$. So $\psi(2n)+\gamma$ is just a re-writing for $H_{2n-1}$.